# Mapping points in 2d space to a sphere

Tags: math, 3d, geometry

I have a bunch of points in a rectangular x/y space which I would like to project onto a sphere. As in, I am trying to write this function:

```
function point_on_sphere(2dx:Number, 2dy:Number) : Vector3D
{
    //magic

    return new Vector3D(3dx, 3dy, 3dz);
}
```

I have been trying to first plot the points on to a cylinder and then map those points to a sphere as directed by [this wikipedia page.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system#Coordinate_system_conversions) However, those formulas assume a constant z=0, which doesn't really do what I want.

I'm using actionscript 3 / flex, but any pseudo code or pushes in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Just to clarify: I'm not trying to apply a texture to a sphere object, but rather to place objects along an imaginary sphere.

Comment: There are many different projections for mapping 2D coordinates onto a sphere. What kind of projection do you want? Do you just want x and y to map to longitude and latitude, or something else?

Comment: Or maybe http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection ?

Comment: I'm looking through Stereographic projection, and it looks to be the way to go. It will take me a bit to get an implementation cooked up, but this should be enough to get me through my mental block. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no one *right* answer. You can choose different approaches based on how you want to place the objects along the sphere.

Is it OK for the objects to get nearer and nearer to each other as you get closer to the sphere's "poles"? Why wouldn't the normal texture-mapping projection actually work for you?

Comment: For the implementation to work ideally for me, the points would have to avoid being bunched up at the top and bottom of the sphere.

Comment: @user518041 - you mentioned in another comment that stereographic projection is fine, but this projection essentially does bunch the points that are 'far away' on the plane to a small area near the pole.